# What is use of Command Builder in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqlcommandbuilder

Command builder builds Parameter Object. What does it mean by parameter object? Why are they created ?

Why does Derive Parameter method need extra round trip to Data store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used it one time (when I needed to import some data and I was too lazy to build out my Sql statements) - to automatically generate insert, update, and delete statements to reconcile changes made to a DataSet with the associated database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx